# How to change font and size in listview

Tags: android, xml, listview, adapter

I must get the items from a listview that already exists and is invisible and I must put the items in another empty listview that is visible. I know there are lots of questions about this, but mine is different. Because I must use it with a RSSReader it is even harder, because I tried to adapt the code but.... How do I transfer the items from the invisible listview, to the visible one and also change the font and the size of the font?

```
TextView feedtitle = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.feedtitle);
        TextView feedpubdate = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.feedpubdate);
        ListView itemlist = (ListView) findViewById(R.id.itemlist);

        if (feed == null)
        {
            feedtitle.setText("No RSS Feed Available");
        return;
        }

        feedtitle.setText(feed.getTitle());
        feedpubdate.setText(feed.getPubDate());

        ArrayAdapter<RSSItem> adapter = new ArrayAdapter<RSSItem>(this,android.R.layout.simple_list_item_1,feed.getAllItems());

        itemlist.setAdapter(adapter);
        itemlist.setOnItemClickListener(this);
        itemlist.setSelection(0);
```

Comment: Why on Earth would you create an `invisible` ListView just to hold the data that goes into another? Would it not be easier to store it in a list/array (which has to be done anyway)?

Comment: I'm also lost on what you're trying to do. Are you trying to update the ListView as you download stuff? Why are you transferring stuff from one ListView to the other?

Comment: Changing the font size can be done by TextView.setTextSize() and the font can be done by `Typeface typeface = Typeface.createFromAsset(getContext().getAssets(),
  "fonts/SFDigitalReadout-Heavy.ttf");` `TextView.setTypeFace(typeface);`

Comment: Aedon... its a listview you cant change the font like that... im usinf an invisible list because im updating a code... and i cant use an array instead of that

Answer (score 0):

You are correct on the textsize, ish.

Please follow this sample. (Note: I am assuming a great deal, such as replace RSSItem with a desired string.)

```
public void MyAdapter extends BaseAdapter {
    List<String> mVisibleData = new ArrayList<String>();
    Queue<String> mInvisibleData = new LinkedList<String>();

    public void addDataToInvisible(String string) {
            mInvisibleData.add(string);
    }

    public void moveInvisibleToVisible() {
        mVisibleData.add(mInvisibleData.poll());
        notifyDataSetChanged();
    }

    @Override public int getCount() {
            return mVisibleData.size();
    }

    @Override public String getItem(int position) {
        return mVisibleData.get(position);
    }

    @Override public long getItemId(int position) {
        return position;
    }

    @Override public View getView(int position, View convertView, ViewGroup parent) {
        TextView ret = new TextView(getContext());
        Typeface tf = Typeface.createFromAsset(getContext().getAssets(), "mtfont.ttf");
        ret.setTypeFace(tf);
        ret.setTextSize(18.0f);
            ret.setText(mVisibleData.get(position);
        return ret;
    }
}
```

Now, you will have to work the finer details, but I am sure this will be close to your needs.

Comment: doesn't work. It gives error at casting the rssitems to strings. I mean it kinda gives errors to all casting that involves the RSS. I need a code that actually gets the items from the listview that is in the xml file...not to get it from the RSS list cause it won't work...